# How to respect an existing WSDL but rename targetNamespace or package containing the services?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

In my project I need to create a service from an existing WSDL. That is easy using a plugin of Eclipse (Buttom -> Top).

So my problem is this :

1. I have 2 files WSDL (howtosmile.wsdl and howtolaugh.wsdl) that I should respect ( the clients exist already for each WSDL - my future web service)
2. The 2 files has the same target targetNamespace : targetNamespace="http://foo.com"

howtosmile.wsdl has these operations :

- **foo1**
- foo2

howtolaugh.wsdl has these operations :

- **foo1**
- foo3

Having the same targetNamespace means that they will point to the same package. If we're lucky we wont have operations in common between the two WSDL. But here **foo1** is in common, and the seconds generated service will erase the previous.

I tried to rename the targetNamespace for the webservice. But now the client complains that he expect another targetNamespace ( the old one ).

**My purpose is to be able to separate the operations of every WSDL in a separate package in the same project.**

Here is where the occurences of targetNamespace, so maybe I might be able to change some and not all of them :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="LocalhellowworldService"
    targetNamespace="http://my.company/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://my.company/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://my.company/Imports">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="hellowworld_schema0.xsd"
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="Ihellowworld_Foo1_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Foo1" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="Ihellowworld_Foo1_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Foo1Response" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="Ihellowworld_Foo2_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Foo2" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="Ihellowworld_Foo2_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Foo2Response" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="Ihellowworld">
        <wsdl:operation name="Foo1">
            <wsdl:input
                wsaw:Action="http://my.company/Ihellowworld/Foo1"
                message="tns:Ihellowworld_Foo1_InputMessage" />
            <wsdl:output
                wsaw:Action="http://my.company/Ihellowworld/Foo1Response"
                message="tns:Ihellowworld_Foo1_OutputMessage" />
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Foo2">
            <wsdl:input
                wsaw:Action="http://my.company/Ihellowworld/Foo2"
                message="tns:Ihellowworld_Foo2_InputMessage" />
            <wsdl:output
                wsaw:Action="http://my.company/Ihellowworld/Foo2Response"
                message="tns:Ihellowworld_Foo2_OutputMessage" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Ihellowworld"
        type="tns:Ihellowworld">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Foo1">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://my.company/Ihellowworld/Foo1"
                style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Foo2">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://my.company/Ihellowworld/Foo2"
                style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="LocalhellowworldService">
        <wsdl:port name="hellowworldPort" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_Ihellowworld">
            <soap:address
                location="http://localhost:8080/server/services/hellowworldPort" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use spring tool suite and Rational Application Developer. Both are implementations of eclipse.

In Spring tool suite we have an option to 'define custom mapping for namespace to packeage'
enable that check box. on next screen you will get an option to map namespace to custom package.

[image]

In RAD,
we have an option to browse the target package.

[image]

Eclise will be having similar options to choose the package for generated classes.